# In which 1950s movie did an industrial factory process abducted humans?

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember little about the film, but it had a lasting impression. It was B+W. I saw it on TV in the early '60s, therefore I think it was a 1950's movie.

The scene I recall vividly: two guys enter the factory to investigate suspicious behavior regarding missing persons. Down in the basement, under large overhead pipes, they can hear objects shoot through the pipes. One of the pipes is leaking. One guy lets some drip onto his hand, only to find the fluid is human blood.

They realize that the whooshing noises coming from the pipes are of human bodies being moved through the pipes from one factory area to another. They decide that the people that were missing are ending up here to be processed. I can't recall what for, or by whom, but probably as food (for aliens?).

They run off in vintage looking vehicles. I seem to recall that they were British, but I can't be sure.

That one scene has remained with me. Every time I see facilities with pipes, I refer to is as an alien human processing plant.

Can anyone help me identify the movie?

Comment: Are you talking about [Soylent Green](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soylent_Green) (1973)?

Comment: No, not Soylent Green - that was much later. I recall seeing this film in the '60s. I think next response suggesting "Enemy from Space" is closer. I'll investigate.

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be "Enemy From Space"(1957)? A.k.a. Quatermass II. Here is a section of the plot description from Wikipedia which mentions the plant and the 'black slime' , which looks like blood in a B & W film. Oh, and the film is British like you said. Here is the part of the Wikipedia page:

Trying to discover what happened to Marsh, Quatermass contacts Inspector Lomax (John Longden), who had previously assisted him (see The Quatermass Xperiment). Lomax puts him in touch with Vincent Broadhead (Tom Chatto), a Member of Parliament, who has been trying to uncover the veil of secrecy surrounding Winnerden Flats. Quatermass joins Broadhead on an official tour of the complex, which he is told has been built to manufacture artificial food. Slipping away from the visiting party, Broadhead attempts to get inside one of the large domes that dominate the skyline. Quatermass later finds him dying, covered in a poisonous black slime.

Comment: THAT'S IT! Here it is on YouTube: https://youtu.be/6G89wt4YxXg . The scene I remember begins at the 59min 40sec mark. I hope you agree that it's as creepy as I remember it to be. Great help - this is why the internet was invited.

Comment: Just kidding, and it looks like an exciting movie.